# EmEditor v20.5.0: JUMP command (go to...) doesn't work

Tags: emeditor

The JUMP command (go to...) doesn't work in EmEditor v20.5.0 and in previous beta versions.
I reverted to the old version, namely 20.4.5, and there is no problem with that command. That is therefore a newly-introduced bug affecting the JUMP command in the latest EmEditor version.

Answer (score 0):

This issue will be fixed on v20.5.1.